# How to extend cookies when user is active - php

Tags: php, html, cookies

I am building an internal log in system for our company intranet. I want to extend the cookies for the username and token if the user is currently active and the cookie is about to expire.

So like such: the user is using the web page and the cookie is going to expire in 20 minutes, how could I extend it for another hour or for a set amount of time?

Here is part of my login script. I'm not showing all of it but this is the part where the cookies are set.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($qryResults); $i++) {
  if( array_key_exists('Token', $qryResults[$i]) ) {
      //check if null or token exists
      if( $qryResults[$i]["length"] == 1 ) {
          $isSuccessful = TRUE;
          $token = $qryResults[$i]["Token"][0];
          //set cookies
          setcookie('username', $username, $expire, '/', 'localhost');
          setcookie('token', $token, $expire, '/', 'localhost');
      }
  }
}
```

I have a login-check every time the user visits the page again, to make sure they have cookies otherwise it sends them to the login page. This is a separate script all on it's own, but just wanted to show it in case it's needed.

```
if(!(isset($_COOKIE["username"])))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

I just need to extend the cookie if it's about to expire and the user is still active.

Comment: why not, in each page, put the setcookie line to restart the expiration timer each time a page is loaded?

Comment: @CraigB Will that work and will I have to then declare the variables in each page as well, such as $username, $token, and $expire?

Comment: surely those need to be declared in each page anyway (to ensure user is logged in)

in my page i declare them from the post to session then to variables, 
and then each page starts with the `if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) { $username = $_SESSION['username'] }` and same for password and then set the cookie expire within the same if block (doing a parent if(isset($_SESSION)) )

not sure if its the best practice or not but it works for how I want it to.

Comment: @CraigB That's why I have a login check, to see if the username exists in a cookie otherwise it makes the user login. I have this check on every page.

Comment: sorry hit enter prematurely, check edit, 

if you're already checking for it to be set then just throw inside that check, the cookie expiry extension.